# Convergence in distribution with empirical distribution function (EDF)

Tags: convergence, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I'm struggling with the following question:

> Let $F_n(x)$ denote the EDF of a random sample. Show that
>
> $\sqrt{n}(F_n(x)-F(x))\xrightarrow[]{d}N(0,F(x)(1-F(x)))$.

I think that the course of action should be:

1. prove that $F_n(x) \xrightarrow[]{p} F(x)$ using the WLLN and
2. prove the convergence in the question using the CLT.

This is my take on the first step: $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(x_i \leq x)$ where $\mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. Then, for all $x$, $\mathbf{1}(x_i \leq x)$ is an iid random variable with expectation $F(x)$. Thus, by the WLLN, $F_n(x)$ is a consistent estimator of $F(x)$: $F_n(x) \xrightarrow[]{p} F(x)$.

So far, so good?

My real troubles begin with the second step. I have set up the expression

$\sqrt{n}(F_n(x)-F(x)) = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(x_i \leq x) - F(x)\right)$

but I don't really know where to go from there. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you know? what did you try?

Comment: Thus far, very little. I did not really know where to start. Apparently, F_n(x) converge in distribution to F(x) by WLLN and the expression in the question should then be derived from the CLT.

Comment: Fix $x$. Then think about variables $Z_i=1(x_i\le x)$. Are they independent? Are they identically distributed? What is their mean and variance?

Comment: Note if $x$ is not fixed, then the question becomes much harder.

Comment: Thanks, @mpiktas ! If you post those two comments as an answer, then I can mark the question as answered. And, a final question, does this mean that my first step is not really needed to answer the question?

Comment: First step is ok. You start with WLLN and then move to CLT. Usually if you are able to check that WLLN holds, then CLT comes easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$. Then think about variables $Z_i=1(x_i\le x)$. Are they independent? Are they identically distributed? What is their mean and variance?

Note that if $x$ is not fixed, then the question becomes much harder.